# Javascript not getting Value from Checkbox in Veleocity for (This) Record in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, velocity

Still really new at Javascript/ jQuery. Here's the scenario... I am using Velocity Template Engine to generate my HTML page. I have custom check boxes on the page that are shaped with Font Awesome icons. My goal is to load the page with the icons either colored or not colored based on the value on the checkbox (which is generated from my database and entered via velocity).

Here is the Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

            var checkedValue = $('.love').val();
            console.log("Checked value is: " + checkedValue);

            if (checkedValue == 'Y') {
                $(".heart").addClass("has-text-danger");
                console.log("if Checked value is: " + checkedValue);

            } else if (checkedValue == 'love') {
                $(".heart").addClass("has-text-danger");
                console.log("else if Checked value is: " + checkedValue);

            } else {
                $(".heart").removeClass("has-text-danger");
                console.log("else Checked value is: " + checkedValue);
            }

    });
```

Here is the snippet of HTML

```
  <div class="columns is-multiline">
    <!-- Here are all of the Amiibo -->
    #foreach( $amiibo in $amiibos )
        <div class="column is-one-fifth">
          <div class="amiibo-id is-hidden" id="amiibo">
          </div>
            <article class="message is-large is-danger">
                <div class="message-header" id="$amiibo.Name">
                    <p></p>
                    <p>$amiibo.Name</p>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <center>   <!-- Amiibo -->
                    <figure class="image has-text-light">
                        <img class="amiibo-image" src="$amiibo.ImageURL" id="inactive-$amiibo.AmiiboID">
                        <!-- Content Over Amiibo -->
                        <figcaption class="overlay is-overlay is-invisible" id="active-$amiibo.AmiiboID">
                            <!-- Background -->
                            <img class="background is-overlay" alt="Mario" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/amiibo/black.png">
                            <div style="height:16px;font-size:16px;">&nbsp;</div>

                            <!-- Buttons -->
                            <div class="tile is-ancestor">

                                <!-- Collected "Mine" (Star) Button -->
                                <div class="tile is-parent">
                                    <article class="tile is-child">
                                        <div class="star">
                                            <label>
                                                <span class="fa-stack">
                                                    <i class="fas fa-star fa-2x"></i>
                                                    <h4 class="subtitle is-5 has-text-light is-bold">Mine</h4>
                                                    <input class="mine is-hidden" type="checkbox" id="mine#$amiibo.AmiiboID#$amiibo.Name">
                                                </span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </article>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Collected "Love" (Heart) Button -->
                                <div class="tile is-parent">
                                    <article class="tile is-child">
                                        <div class="heart">
                                            <label>
                                                <span class="fa-stack">
                                                    <i class="fas fa-heart fa-2x"></i>
                                                    <h4 class="subtitle is-5 has-text-light is-bold">Love</h4>
                                                    <input class="love is-hidden" type="checkbox" id="love#$amiibo.AmiiboID#$amiibo.Name" value="$amiibo.Favorited">
                                                </span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </article>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Collected "Want" (Gem) Button -->
                                <div class="tile is-parent">
                                    <article class="tile is-child">
                                        <div class="gem">
                                            <label>
                                                <span class="fa-stack">
                                                    <i class="fas fa-gem fa-2x"></i>
                                                    <h4 class="subtitle is-5 has-text-light is-bold">Want</h4>
                                                    <input class="want is-hidden" type="checkbox" id="want#$amiibo.AmiiboID#$amiibo.Name">
                                                </span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </article>
                                </div>

                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </center>
            </article>
        </div>
    #end
</div>
```

The problem is I am getting a checked value of: $amiibo.Favorited instead of 'Y' or 'N' which is what should be generating from velocity via value="$amiibo.Favorited

I am open to better ways to handle this also.

**EDIT:
So I changed some data, it looks like its /sort of/ working... I'm finding that if the first iteration in my #foreach in velocity is set to Y or another value, then all of the subsequent divs get the same value from the javascript. I think there is a problem with "THIS", but still not sure how to fix.**

Thank you! 
Travis W.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the way I am doing this. I am now using conditionals with velocity. It is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the **escaping of the dollar sign** problem... you can try replace `&#36;amiibo.Favorited` instead of `$amiibo.Favorited` in the html elements in this case for the

Comment: Good thought, but same results.